# tikzDevice main caption without boldface

Tags: r, latex, tikzdevice

I have recently started using tikzDevice in R to create plots to be compiled in LaTeX. However, I haven't found a way to get rid of the boldface font in the main caption.

As an example, I create the following graph in R:

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz(file = 'example.tex', standAlone = TRUE)
plot(1, main = 'Plot of $\\hat{\\beta}$')
dev.off()
```

Which produces the necessary LaTeX output but introduces `{\bfseries Plot of $\hat{\beta}$}`. This is particularly unpleasant when, as in the example, math in normal font is paired with bold face text. I'm interested in removing the `\bfseries` from within R, as I need to produce several plots within a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tikzDevice` just translates the R plot. And in R titles are in bold by default. You can change that using `font.main = 1`:

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz(file = 'example.tex', standAlone = TRUE)
plot(1, font.main = 1, main = 'Plot of $\\hat{\\beta}$')
dev.off()
```